# Getting null from radiobutton value in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

(I checked all the other similar questions and I am a newbie let me say first)

I have html in very basic terms like this: https://ibb.co/KVNbv9z
And  a  servlet code like below.

which gives null return for the String q1 :/

I think the main problem is I am trying to use request.getRequestDispatcher("htmlquestions.html").include(request, response); 
inside the servlet , but can not get return its result back. What should I do- I am searching for 2 days for this. Appreciated big  for your help

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class SecondServlet extends HttpServlet {




public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response){
try{


response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


request.getRequestDispatcher("htmlquestions.html").include(request,     response); 


String q1 = request.getParameter("Q1");

out.print(  " aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa     " + q1 );


out.print("<form action='ThirdServlet'>");
out.print("<input type='submit' value='go'>");
out.print("</form>");


out.close();

}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
```

}

Comment: What's the URL you use to call this servlet? i.e. what does your browser address bar contain when you're looking at the output of this servlet? Why do you think q1 should not be null?

Comment: Hi Nizet. I use it in Eclipse with a loginpage(http://localhost:8081/lab4/index.html) . But no problem at that stage I guess. My aim is using "htmlquestions.html" inside the servlet (to show the questions) and get its results back if it is possible. Why it gets null is probably the code is executed even before I click somewhere on the form:) but I don't know where/how to fix it indeed

Comment: That's the URL of your index.html page. Probably not the URL of the page returned by this servlet. Your intuition is correct. This servlet **displays** a form. Displaying a form doesn't allow accessing the parameters that would be sent when **submitting** the form. You need to submit the form, and get the parameter  in the servlet handling this submission.

Comment: thank you. I use this http://localhost:8081/lab4/Login to call the servlet ,  this is servlet url       http://localhost:8081/lab4/SecondServlet,  and this is result of the servlet   url http://localhost:8081/lab4/ThirdServlet                So do you mean I should use submit in html then it will be ok?

Comment: I mean that you should understand how this works. Displaying a form is not the same thing than handling the submission of a form. It's only when you handle the submission of a form that you can access the values submitted by the user. Not when displaying it. When displaying it, the user hasn't seen the form yet, and thus can't possibly have sent anything.

Comment: You are perfectly wise to me to catch the fish., thank you very much indeed Nizet. It is fixed when I did as you said (putting submit in the html form element) :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Java EE docs:

https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

> void include(ServletRequest request,
>                ServletResponse response)
>         throws ServletException,
>                IOException
>
> Includes the content of a resource (servlet, JSP page, HTML file) in
>   the response. In essence, this method enables programmatic server-side
>   includes.

You are just including content in the **response**, the request is not changed. The request parameters are set when the form is submitted. This is why `request.getParameter` returns null, there is no value set when the request is received by the servlet.

To do what you want, you should create a JSP form, or better a JSF form that includes the content on page rendering. I strongly suggest you to use JSF, as using servlets and/or JSP to create Web content is somewhat deprecated and can get very messy as the content becomes more complex.

Comment: Thank you whbogado, as the other friend and you pointed out, submitting form in the html did the trick. Thank you much